# Android activity/array adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

i am having trouble retrieving items in an array in the adapter, hope somebody can show me the light...

in my app, i use a lot of listView and using array adapter to display the data in the row and i am fine with that.

My activity

```
protected void onPostExecute(CarDetail list) {
   List<CarPhotos> photos = list.getPhotos();
         System.out.println("retrieving Photos");
         for (CarPhotos photo : photos) {
            PhotoArray.add(photo);
            System.out.println(photo);
        }
}
System.out.println(PhotoArray.size());
photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My adapter (Usually use this to display data in a row within a list)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ViewHolder holder;
    //Get the current location object
    CarPhotos lm = (CarPhotos) getItem(position);


    ......etc
    holder.thumbnailname.setText(lm.getThumbnailName());
return convertView;
}
```

But what if i want to get the count and all the item in that array instead of the specific row position, how could i do that?  (i.e.: list all the thumbnail names out and count in 1 cell/row)

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Do you want to set the size of your array list in Adapter class?

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal yes, i want to retrieve the size (length), create a loop and display all the items with the adapter... instead of row by row

Comment: @SArumik I'm confused, whats the difference between displaying all the items and showing them row by row? `photoAdapter.getCount()` will give you the size. But I still dont understand how a loop is going to help you here. `ListView` automatically loops through and calls `getView` for each of your items...

Comment: User photoArray.size(); Adapter is used to inflate data row by row

Comment: actually i am using mergeadapter to create a listView to stitch together 2 listView and 2 normal view. And in this case i want to get the data in that array and show it in a view instead of a list row... which i couldn't figure out how, so i just display the data in the same adapter but just within 1 row... =(

Comment: Can you please show us all the code in your `Adapter`. I already see things wrong, but I don't want to answer with the little info I have. And what exactly is the issue? Are you getting errors, or are somethings not showing up...